# Modify a specific line in HTML using grunt task

Tags: html, gruntjs, versioning

I have a line in my html file like
    `<script type="text/javascript" src="/path/jsfilename.js?ver=123">`
The goal is to update the version number `?ver=123` by timestamp or some dynamic entity everytime the js file is updated on the server. How can I achieve this with a grunt task?